# Como criar uma função no R

Tags: r, funções

Estou querendo criar uma função para controle das notas dos alunos. Estou tentando a seguinte função:

```
note_eng<-read.csv2("note.csv",header=TRUE)

note_eng$Média<-(note_eng[,1]+note_eng[,2]+note_eng[,3])/3

for(i in 1:length(note_eng$Média)){
    if(note_eng$Média[i]>=7) 
    note_eng$Resultado[i]="Aprovado" 
else
    note_eng$Resultado[i]="Reprovado"
}
```

Mas o que gostaria seria o seguinte:

Formato do data.frame:

Matrícula   1ª Prova   2ª Prova   3ª Prova   Média   Prova Final   Média Final

1º) Se a nota de cada prova for maior ou igual a 7 a cor do texto seria azul enquanto em caso contrário a cor do texto seria vermelha

2º) Calcular a média das três provas;

3º) Gerar uma nova coluna em que:
Se a média for maior ou igual a 7 o resultado seria Aprovado (se possível cor do texto azul) e, nesse caso (média>=7) já colocar o resultado na coluna Média Final
Se a média for maior que quatro e menor do que 7 o resultado seria Prova Final (cor do texto preta e fundo amarelo)
Se a média for menor do que quatro o resultado seria Reprovado (cor do texto vermelha)

4º) Caso o aluno for para a Prova Final, calcular a Média Final em que `(Média*0,6)+(Prova Final*0,4)` e se a nota for maior do que 5 o resultado é Aprovado (cor do texto azul) caso contrário Reprovado (cor do texto vermelha) e colocar o resultado na coluna Média Final

Alguém saberia como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Antes de responder, algumas considerações:

1. Recomendo não usar variáveis com acentos, você pode ter problema com *encoding*.
2. Você pode calcular a média com a função `mean()`, ou como vou mostrar abaixo, `rowMeans()` ao invés de somar tudo e dividir.
3. Não tem como colocar texto em azul, a não ser que você vá fazer uma imagem. Os arquivos .csv não tem formatação deste tipo, e acho que não vale a pena salvar em outros formatos (como .xlsx) só por isso.

Sobre o código:

Aqui vai uma opção bem passo-a-passo. Como você certamente vai ter que adaptar, deixei assim pra mostrar a ideia.

```
notas <- data.frame(Mat=1:4, P1=c(8, 2, 5, 6), P2=c(9, 3, 7, 4), P3=c(10, 4, 6, 7))
notas$media <- rowMeans(notas[,2:4])
notas$resultado <- cut(notas$media, breaks=c(0, 4, 7, 10), labels=c("Reprovado", "PFinal", "Aprovado"))
notas$pfinal <- c(NA, NA, 8, 2)
notas$media.final <- notas$media*0.6+notas$pfinal*0.4
notas$resultado.final <- NA
notas[which(notas$media.final>=5),]$resultado.final <- "Aprovado"
notas[which(notas$media.final<5),]$resultado.final <- "Reprovado"
notas[which(notas$resultado=="Aprovado"),]$resultado.final <- "Aprovado"
notas[which(notas$resultado=="Reprovado"),]$resultado.final <- "Reprovado"
notas
```

Note que você não precisa usar loops. A função `cut()` transforma uma variável numérica (`media`) em variáveis categóricas (`labels`) de acordo com os limites passados (`breaks`). Você pode procurar uma maneira de usá-la também para o calculo do resultado final, talvez substituindo os valores de NA por 0 ou 10 pra quem for reprovado ou aprovado, respectivamente.

Comment: Algumas informações adicionais: No exemplo inventei as notas de quatro alunos, um para cada caso possível. O primeiro foi aprovado direto, o segundo reprovado direto, e os outros dois foram para PFinal, sendo o primeiro aprovado e o segundo reprovado.